# Magento 2 How to populated admin ui form element from DB table

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am trying to create a admin UI form in my custom module. But, when I am in edit form, I can't see my for elements populated by my module db table. 
Suppose, there is a 'title' column in my table and it contains data but I can't populate that title textbox from db table entry.

Here is my DataProvider and UI form xml: 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Module namespace: CompanyName
Module name: MenuManager

**DataProvider.php**

```
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{ 

    protected $_loadedData; 
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $menumanagerCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $menumanagerCollectionFactory->create(); 
       parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    } 

    /*public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter) {
        return null; 
    } */

    /**
     * Get data  
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {

        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        $ruleId = '';
        foreach ($items as $page) {
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
            //$ruleId = $page->getId();
        } 
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**companyname_menumanager_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">companyname_menumanager_form.companyname_menumanager_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">companyname_menumanager_form.companyname_menumanager_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="menumanager" xsi:type="string">companyname_menumanager_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
        <deps>
            <dep>companyname_menumanager_form.companyname_menumanager_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="categorytree_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">CompanyName\MenuManager\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">companyname_menumanager_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
                <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url" />
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="categorytree_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="title" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="categories" component="CompanyName_MenuManager/js/select-category" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <required>true</required>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Select Category</label>
                <dataScope>data.categories</dataScope>
                <componentType>field</componentType>
                <listens>
                    <link name="${ $.companyname }.${ $.companyname }:responseData">setParsed</link>
                </listens>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="CompanyName\MenuManager\Ui\Component\Form\Category\Options"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>    


    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: It's solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In DataProvider.php change below line with my answer:

```
foreach ($items as $page) {
        $this->loadedData['categorytree_details'][$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
        //$ruleId = $page->getId();
    }
```

when your ui form left side tabs you add you have return data with field set

if you remove below code from your companyname_menumanager_form.xml file

```
      <layout>
        <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
        <type>tabs</type>
    </layout>
```

then no need to add filedset in dataprovider.

> **so just add filedset whenever you require leftside tab in your form.**

Comment: there was problem in form xml file which was related to tag 'dataScope'. I already fixed it. Thanks for your answer though.